# How to get 'Distance to Nearest ATM' from 'Distance' attribute of API JSON Response?

Tags: python, json, pandas, response, json-normalize

I have a sample API response as follows, It has the nearest ATMs for a given latitude/Longitude. I will be executing this API for Input from a pandas DataFrame which has two columns for Latitude/Longitude. I want the output as 'Distance to the Nearest ATM' for each location as another column in the original dataframe. The JSON entries have an attribute 'Distance' from which 'Distance to the Nearest ATM' will be derived.
The Response has 20 Nearest ATM Entries.
The following is a sample JSON Response for one of the locations from my input dataframe-

````
{'results': {'items': [{'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['6113'],
                        'distance': 727,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-9b94731a418e41848c81389e9bbb5258;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0w?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-9b94731a418e41848c81389e9bbb5258',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT09H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T090000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 09:00 - 18:00'},
                        'position': [40.71001, -74.00979],
                        'title': 'Capital One',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '176 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10038'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['2667'],
                        'distance': 58,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-ce5c5899421348eab75d05794548b34f;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0x?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-ce5c5899421348eab75d05794548b34f',
                        'position': [40.70382, -74.01174],
                        'title': 'TD Bank',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '90 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 321,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-efead63cf9b940a7a228c6e8bce1bfab;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0y?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-efead63cf9b940a7a228c6e8bce1bfab',
                        'position': [40.70526, -74.01422],
                        'title': 'Berkshire Bank',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '5 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10004'},
                       {'alternativeNames': [{'language': 'en',
                                              'name': 'TD BANK ATM'}],
                        'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['2667'],
                        'distance': 457,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-ff3977a80edd4e80a2ffbb60c5f04dcb;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0z?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-ff3977a80edd4e80a2ffbb60c5f04dcb',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT10H30M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T080000'},
                                                        {'duration': 'PT05H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:SA',
                                                         'start': 'T090000'},
                                                        {'duration': 'PT04H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:SU',
                                                         'start': 'T110000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 08:00 - '
                                                 '18:30<br/>Sat: 09:00 - '
                                                 '14:00<br/>Sun: 11:00 - '
                                                 '15:00'},
                        'position': [40.70766, -74.01137],
                        'title': 'TD Bank',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '2 Wall St<br/>New York, NY 10005'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['1165'],
                        'distance': 522,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-f5fabc4d9f7141b1a21317c840bacdb9;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz00?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-f5fabc4d9f7141b1a21317c840bacdb9',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT08H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T090000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 09:00 - 17:00'},
                        'position': [40.70823, -74.01056],
                        'title': 'Citibank',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '120 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10271'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['1290'],
                        'distance': 1341,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-35b9d23eef9e44c38a8339285bd801c1;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz01?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-35b9d23eef9e44c38a8339285bd801c1',
                        'position': [40.71535, -74.00782],
                        'title': 'Bank of America',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '168 Church St<br/>New York, NY 10007'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['1106'],
                        'distance': 567,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-aa24fe86f42b4815bf757280b552118d;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz02?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-aa24fe86f42b4815bf757280b552118d',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT08H30M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T083000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 08:30 - 17:00'},
                        'position': [40.708655, -74.01111],
                        'title': 'HSBC',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '117 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10006'},
                       {'alternativeNames': [{'language': 'en',
                                              'name': 'Federal Reserve Bank'}],
                        'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 609,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-ae53f05b1f9e4cb181fc29c2fd8efd40;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz03?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-ae53f05b1f9e4cb181fc29c2fd8efd40',
                        'position': [40.708861, -74.009352],
                        'title': 'Federal Reserve Bank of New York',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '33 Liberty Pl<br/>New York, NY 10038'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 660,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-2719b12b4b244b8b808dd34014a66e63;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz04?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-2719b12b4b244b8b808dd34014a66e63',
                        'position': [40.70944, -74.01012],
                        'title': 'Berkshire Bancorp',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '160 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10038'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 1191,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-00e631bb6a614c74a85060fc21ddb9d7;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz05?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-00e631bb6a614c74a85060fc21ddb9d7',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': True,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT24H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU',
                                                         'start': 'T000000'}],
                                         'text': 'Tue-Sun: 00:00 - 00:00'},
                        'position': [40.71392, -74.01469],
                        'title': 'American Express Company',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '200 Vesey St<br/>New York, NY 10281'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'chainIds': ['1290'],
                        'distance': 1204,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-2692d9fbb3384f33af3d5eddce3fcf73;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xMA?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-2692d9fbb3384f33af3d5eddce3fcf73',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT09H30M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T083000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 08:30 - 18:00'},
                        'position': [40.71386, -74.00676],
                        'title': 'Bank of America',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '261 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10007'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 1453,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/8403fv6k-0cf06c8d42f40193e3a9b8084fe4e33d;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xMQ?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '8403fv6k-0cf06c8d42f40193e3a9b8084fe4e33d',
                        'position': [40.71551, -74.00421],
                        'title': 'Justice Federal Credit Union',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '26 Federal Plz<br/>New York, NY 10278'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 50,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/8403fv6k-621152dd2a180b3f25443a0eb5ce68e2;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xNg?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '8403fv6k-621152dd2a180b3f25443a0eb5ce68e2',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': True,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT12H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA',
                                                         'start': 'T090000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Sat: 09:00 - 21:00'},
                        'position': [40.70395, -74.01143],
                        'title': 'New York Cash Net',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '85 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/hospital-health-care-facility?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'hospital-health-care-facility',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'Hospital or Healthcare Facility',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 50,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/8408lxx5-925d315190cb060336acf064d68ea7a7;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xNw?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/26.icon',
                        'id': '8408lxx5-925d315190cb060336acf064d68ea7a7',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT08H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T090000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 09:00 - 17:00'},
                        'position': [40.70395, -74.01143],
                        'title': 'Life Mod',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '85 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/hospital-health-care-facility?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'hospital-health-care-facility',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'Hospital or Healthcare Facility',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 50,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-72136d2caf4d41aca1a2daa21789e10b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xOA?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/26.icon',
                        'id': '840dr5re-72136d2caf4d41aca1a2daa21789e10b',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT06H30M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR',
                                                         'start': 'T070000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Fri: 07:00 - 13:30'},
                        'position': [40.70395, -74.01143],
                        'title': 'Symbio Physiotherapy',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '85 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004'},
                       {'averageRating': 0.0,
                        'category': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                                     'id': 'atm-bank-exchange',
                                     'system': 'places',
                                     'title': 'ATM/Bank/Exchange',
                                     'type': 'urn:nlp-types:category'},
                        'distance': 50,
                        'having': [],
                        'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/8408lxx5-158041e5aa340aea0d37533b0914dd91;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0xOQ?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'icon': 'https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon',
                        'id': '8408lxx5-158041e5aa340aea0d37533b0914dd91',
                        'openingHours': {'isOpen': False,
                                         'label': 'Opening hours',
                                         'structured': [{'duration': 'PT12H00M',
                                                         'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA',
                                                         'start': 'T080000'}],
                                         'text': 'Mon-Sat: 08:00 - 20:00'},
                        'position': [40.70395, -74.01143],
                        'title': 'Fast Payday Loan',
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place',
                        'vicinity': '85 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004'}],
             'next': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/explore;context=Y2F0PWF0bS1iYW5rLWV4Y2hhbmdlJTJDaG9zcGl0YWwtaGVhbHRoLWNhcmUtZmFjaWxpdHkmZmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmb2Zmc2V0PTIwJnNpemU9MjA?in=40.703553%2C-74.011152%3Br%3D2000.0&app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg'},
 'search': {'context': {'href': 'https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPTYwK1BlYXJsK1N0O2xhdD00MC43MDM1NTM7bG9uPS03NC4wMTExNTI7c3RyZWV0PVBlYXJsK1N0O2hvdXNlPTYwO2NpdHk9TmV3K1lvcms7cG9zdGFsQ29kZT0xMDAwNDtjb3VudHJ5PVVTQTtkaXN0cmljdD1GaW5hbmNpYWwrRGlzdHJpY3Q7c3RhdGVDb2RlPU5ZO2NvdW50eT1OZXcrWW9yaztjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWJ1aWxkaW5nO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbA;context=c2VhcmNoQ29udGV4dD0x?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg',
                        'location': {'address': {'city': 'New York',
                                                 'country': 'United States',
                                                 'countryCode': 'USA',
                                                 'county': 'New York',
                                                 'district': 'Financial '
                                                             'District',
                                                 'house': '60',
                                                 'postalCode': '10004',
                                                 'stateCode': 'NY',
                                                 'street': 'Pearl St',
                                                 'text': '60 Pearl St<br/>New '
                                                         'York, NY '
                                                         '10004<br/>USA'},
                                     'position': [40.703553, -74.011152]},
                        'type': 'urn:nlp-types:place'}}} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

- With `data` equal to your sample.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data['results']['items'])

# extract lat & long from position
df[['lat', 'long']] = pd.DataFrame(df.position.tolist(), index=df.index)

# drop position column
df.drop(columns='position', inplace=True)

# move position x & y to index 3 & 4
col = df.pop('lat')
df.insert(3, col.name, col)
col = df.pop('long')
df.insert(4, col.name, col)

# remove chainIds from list
df = df.explode('chainIds')

print(df.head(3))

 averageRating chainIds  distance       lat      long having                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               href                                                                              icon                                         id           title                 type                             vicinity                                                                                                                                category.href        category.id category.system     category.title           category.type openingHours.isOpen openingHours.label                                                                          openingHours.structured       openingHours.text alternativeNames
           0.0     6113       727  40.71001 -74.00979     []  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-9b94731a418e41848c81389e9bbb5258;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0w?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon  840dr5re-9b94731a418e41848c81389e9bbb5258     Capital One  urn:nlp-types:place  176 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10038  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  atm-bank-exchange          places  ATM/Bank/Exchange  urn:nlp-types:category               False      Opening hours  [{'duration': 'PT09H00M', 'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR', 'start': 'T090000'}]  Mon-Fri: 09:00 - 18:00              NaN
           0.0     2667        58  40.70382 -74.01174     []  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-ce5c5899421348eab75d05794548b34f;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0x?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon  840dr5re-ce5c5899421348eab75d05794548b34f         TD Bank  urn:nlp-types:place   90 Broad St<br/>New York, NY 10004  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  atm-bank-exchange          places  ATM/Bank/Exchange  urn:nlp-types:category                 NaN                NaN                                                                                              NaN                     NaN              NaN
           0.0      NaN       321  40.70526 -74.01422     []  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/840dr5re-efead63cf9b940a7a228c6e8bce1bfab;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0wMTA4YmNmMy01M2MxLTUyZmItOWMyYS1hZTg0ZDFjMWFhOWJfMTU4NzA4Mzg0MTUzMV8wXzg0NjYmcmFuaz0y?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/15.icon  840dr5re-efead63cf9b940a7a228c6e8bce1bfab  Berkshire Bank  urn:nlp-types:place    5 Broadway<br/>New York, NY 10004  https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/categories/places/atm-bank-exchange?app_id=NRCOCm4yupXp5UUkFhyU&app_code=OqBcuShIgWoRS_NjlxDwfg  atm-bank-exchange          places  ATM/Bank/Exchange  urn:nlp-types:category                 NaN                NaN                                                                                              NaN                     NaN              NaN
```

### Just `distance` with a `for-loop`

- `distance` is inside a `list`, so you need to iterate through each list to get the value.

```py
for dist in data['results']['items']:
    print(dist.get('distance'))

727
58
321
457
522
1341
567
609
660
1191
1204
1453
50
50
50
50
```